# query & where in Firebase (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How i can make query in firebase? On oracle sql the query would be

```
"select * from users where username = "SomeUser"
```

I need to do the same in Firebase, Swift 3

[image]

Comment: show your firebase database structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `queryOrderedByChild` and `queryStartingAtValue`. This should get you started in the right direction.

**queryStartingAtValue(username).queryEndingAtValue(username)**

```
let username = "SomeUser"

FIRDatabase.database().reference.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryStartingAtValue(username).queryEndingAtValue(username).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

}
```

**queryEqual(toValue: username)**

```
let searchRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username)
```

Comment: Why would you need both `.queryStartingAtValue(username)` and `.queryEndingAtValue(username)`? Is there a simpler way to just search for all results of a certain value? I see there's some `queryEqual(toValue: Any?)` function.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 && Firebase 3

I hope this will help you understand. Here we go

This is example of the data structure:
[image: Example]

And here is the code:

```
    let username = "DavidMouse"

    // create searchRef or queryRef you name it
    let searchRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username)

    // search the username
    searchRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard snapshot.value is NSNull else {

            // yes we got the user
            let user = snapshot.value as! String
            print("\(user) is exists")
            return
        }

        // no there is no user with desire username
        print("\(username) is exists")
    }) { (error) in
        print("Failed to get snapshot", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: In this case, we can order our list elements by values nested under the `users` key by specifying the relative path to the nested child in our queryOrderedByChild call.