# Read data with conditional from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need conditional for code, which read data from Firebase. I want conditional like is in SQL "WHERE project = 'test'". I write it in Swift.

I have this code for read data from Firebase:

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?
var tasks = [Task]()
var uid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! as String

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("\(uid)/Tasks")

    startObservetingDB()
}

func startObservetingDB() {
    ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newSweets = [Task]()

        for sweet in snapshot.children {
            let sweetObject = Task(snapshot: sweet as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newSweets.append(sweetObject)
        }

        self.tasks = newSweets
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error:Error) -> Void in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksCell", for: indexPath) as! TasksCell

    let arrayTasks = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.taskName.text = arrayTasks.content

    return cell
}
```

And I have this Firebase structure:

[image: My Firebase structure]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the tasks for a specific project with:

```
ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "project").queryEqual(toValue: "test").observe(.childAdded
```

But you might also want to consider if your data structure is optimal for your usage. It seems likely that you'll most often (maybe even always?) will show the tasks for a specific project. In that case it is more efficient to store the data in that structure:

```
ProjectTasks
    $ProjectId (e.g. "test")
        $TaskId ("asd asd se")
```

Btw: this answer seems *highly* related: [query & where in Firebase (swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038228/query-where-in-firebase-swift-3)

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, but if I change structure, how can I edit "$ProjectId (e.g. "test")"? I know that I must use "updateChildValues", but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Your project id should be an auto-generated, meaningless key. You should never have to edit it. The name of your project is metadata, which should be the value of a property. E.g. `/Projects/$ProjectId: { name: "test" }`.